# reference to a sequence column (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, reference, sequences

I encountered a problem when creating a foreign key referencing to a sequence, see the code example below.
But on creating the tables i recieve the following error.
"Detail: Key columns "product" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and ownseq"
I've already tried different datatypes for the product column (like smallint, bigint) but none of them is accepted.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ownseq INCREMENET BY 1 MINVALUE 100 MAXVALUE 99999;  
CREATE TABLE products (  
id ownseq PRIMARY KEY,  
...);

CREATE TABLE basket (
basket_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
product INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES products(id));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ownseq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 100 MAXVALUE 99999;  
CREATE TABLE products (  
    id integer PRIMARY KEY default nextval('ownseq'),
    ...
);
alter sequence ownseq owned by products.id;
```

The key change is that `id` is defined as an `integer`, rather than as `ownseq`. This is what would happen if you used the `SERIAL` pseudo-type to create the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
    CREATE TABLE products (  
    id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval(('ownseq'::text)::regclass) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  
    ...);
```

or don't create the sequence ownseq and let postgres do it for you:

```
    CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ...);
```

In the above case the name of the sequence postgres has create should be `products_id_seq`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `primary key` implies `not null` so the latter is not necessary.

Comment: And yes, depending on the version a cast to `regclass` is necessary.

Comment: Does this syntax creates the sequence within the "create table"statement?
And would it be possible to set a minimum value and maximum value like the original statement?

Comment: @DJake Do you mean the `serial`syntax? If yes see the [documentation of serial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). It is _merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns_ and its equivalent is a series of statements. One of those statements is a `CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq`. Minimum or maximum values seem not to be possible here.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL is powerful and you have just been bitten by an advanced feature.

Your DDL is quite valid but not at all what you think it is.

A sequence can be thought of as an extra-transactional simple table used for generating next values for some columns.

**What you meant to do**

You meant to have the id field defined thus, as per the other answer:

```
id integer PRIMARY KEY default nextval('ownseq'),
```

**What you did**

What you did was actually define a nested data structure for your table.  Suppose I create a test sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE testseq;
```

Then suppose I `\d testseq` on Pg 9.1, I get:

```
           Sequence "public.testseq"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value        
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | testseq
 last_value    | bigint  | 1
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 0
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | f
```

This is the definition of the type the sequence used.

Now suppose I:

```
 create table seqtest (test testseq, id serial);
```

I can insert into it:

```
 INSERT INTO seqtest (id, test) values (default, '("testseq",3,4,1,133445,1,1,0,f,f)');
```

I can then select from it:

```
select * from seqtest;
               test               | id 
----------------------------------+----
 (testseq,3,4,1,133445,1,1,0,f,f) |  2
```

Moreover I can expand test:

```
SELECT (test).* from seqtest;

select (test).* from seqtest;
 sequence_name | last_value | start_value | increment_by | max_value | min_value
 | cache_value | log_cnt | is_cycled | is_called 
---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+----------
-+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------
               |            |             |              |           |          
 |             |         |           | 
 testseq       |          3 |           4 |            1 |    133445 |         1
 |           1 |       0 | f         | f
(2 rows)
```

This sort of thing is actually very powerful in PostgreSQL but full of unexpected corners (for example not null and check constraints don't work as expected with nested data types).  I don't generally recommend nested data types, but it is worth knowing that PostgreSQL can do this and will be happy to accept SQL commands to do it without warning.